# Change Django to use EmailMultiAlternatives instead of send_mail() by default (all-auth)

Tags: django, email, django-allauth

So I am using django-all-auth for my authentication and using its in-built functionality for mailing reset passwords, confirmations of registration, etc.  I have designed templates that include images. For the regular emails, I am explicitly using functions that use EmailMultiAlternatives instead of send_mail() since that allows inline images and background images.
Django-all-auth however automatically uses send_mail() and my emails are arriving with the images missing.
How can I override it so it uses EmailMultiAlternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making an adapter that modified send_mail and render_mail methods of the account adapter (allauth.account.adapter.DefaultAccountAdapter).

In it I attached the images I wanted via functions I call (logo_data and background_data). The images are dynamic hence the function.

```
class Adapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    # Redirect after succesfull login

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):

            return reverse('landing-dashboard')

        

    def render_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context, headers=None):

        """

        Renders an email to `email`.  `template_prefix` identifies the

        email that is to be sent, e.g. "account/email/email_confirmation"

        """

        to = [email] if isinstance(email, str) else email

        subject = render_to_string("{0}_subject.txt".format(template_prefix), context)

        # remove superfluous line breaks

        subject = " ".join(subject.splitlines()).strip()

        subject = self.format_email_subject(subject)



        from_email = self.get_from_email()



        bodies = {}

        for ext in ["html", "txt"]:

            try:

                template_name = "{0}_message.{1}".format(template_prefix, ext)

                bodies[ext] = render_to_string(

                    template_name,

                    context,

                    self.request,

                ).strip()

            except TemplateDoesNotExist:

                if ext == "txt" and not bodies:

                    # We need at least one body

                    raise

        if "txt" in bodies:

            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(

                subject, bodies["txt"], from_email, to, headers=headers

            )

            if "html" in bodies:

                msg.attach_alternative(bodies["html"], "text/html")

                msg.attach(logo_data())

                msg.attach(background_data())

        else:

            msg = EmailMessage(subject, bodies["html"], from_email, to, headers=headers)

            msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html

        return msg



    def send_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):

        msg = self.render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)

        msg.send()
```